# How to access a column in laravel query result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm getting an error in my controller `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$created_at`

How can I access a column `created_at` from a result of laravel query?

Controller Code:

```
    public function getDashboard() {
        $posts=Post::latest('created_at')->get();
        dd($posts->created_at);
  //      $posts->created_at=Carbon::parse($posts->created_at)->diffForHumans(Carbon::now());
        return view('dashboard',compact('posts'));
    }
```

It works with `findOrFail(some_id)` but not with this, why?

Comment: If that code works with `findOrFail` then something is wrong. Also, instead of setting `Post::created_at` in a controller you could use an accessor in your model. [Look here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators "Laravel mutators")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`get()` returns collection, so you need to iterate over it:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->created_at;
}
```

Or you could use `first()` to get object instead of collection. In this case this would work:

```
$post = Post::latest()->first();
$post->created_at;
```

Also, you don't need to pass `created_at` to `latest()`, because this column is defined as default:

```
public function latest($column = 'created_at')
```

Comment: will `first()` return all rows?

Comment: No, it will return only one object (first one). If you have multiple items, using `foreach` is the only option.

Comment: It's throwing an error `A two digit month could not be found
Data missing`. Code updated!

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri it's not related to original question and you should create another question, post the error etc. I think you can't do `$post->created_at=` and also you don't need to parse `created_at` since it's already an instance of Carbon.

Answer (score 2):

As `$post` is an instance `Collection` you have to use `foreach` as:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    dd($post->created_at);
}
```

Or you can use `first` to get first object or `last` to get last object as

```
dd($posts->first()->created_at);

dd($posts->last()->created_at);
```

**Update**

Try it as:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->diff_for_humans = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

Then your can access it as:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    dd($post->diff_for_humans);
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, call the `->first()` method on the query rather than collection itself, if 1 result is all that is needed.

Comment: It's throwing an error A two digit month could not be found Data missing. Code updated!

Answer (score 0):

when you call `get()` you can pass an array of fields to select:

```
$posts = Post::latest()->get(['created_at']);
```

then dump to see, what is inside with `dd($post)`